# Is horizontal scrolling of 0 height element not cross browser compatible?

Tags: html, css, w3c

Please open the following example in different browsers:

```css
  .marquee-content {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 30px;
    }
    
    .marquee {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .marquee-horizontal .horizontal-wrapper {
        width: 10000px;
    }
    
   
    
    .marquee-horizontal .marquee-content {
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="marquee marquee-horizontal">
        <div class="horizontal-wrapper">
          
                <div class="marquee-content">
                  On chrome browser I have a small horizontal scrollbar. But on Firefox I have a long scrollbar.  On chrome browser I have a small horizontal scrollbar. But on Firefox I have a long scrollbar.
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

On chrome browser the horizontal scrolling is as long as the text content. But o Firefox it is 10,000px long as per the width `.horizontal-wrapper`. It's due to `.horizontal-wrapper` having 0 height. So my question is:

- As per w3c latest draft what is the expected behaviour of scrolling when child element is very long but has 0 height?
- Which browser, Chrome or Firefox, has implemented the w3c spec correctly?

Comment: This is about CSS, not HTML. Why would you refer to the HTML spec and not the CSS spec?

Comment: @BoltClock I thought scrolling is html behavior independent of css.